# Saving/Writing/Adding file to upload folder

Tags: plugins, images, uploads

Within a plugin I am generating an image, I would like to save this image to the upload folder and update the WPDB with the location of said file. I cant find any build in wordpress functions to handle saving/writing/adding a file to the upload folder, should I just do this the old fashioned way with php, or is there something built into WordPress that I'm missing?

Comment: Have a look at [media_handle_upload](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload)

Answer (score 2):

Check into the functions: [wp_handle_upload()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload) and [media_handle_upload()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload)

Answer (score 0):

You need only to save generated file in the upload folder!... Use php.

If you need to add this file in `Media libary` than use [wp_insert_attachment()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment)